# Why won't MSBuild deploy a web site with settings that work on other projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I've been successfully using MSBuild to deploy a web site for several months. I recently needed to deploy a second site, but the same configuration will not deploy the new site. I can deploy the site with the Visual Studio Publish dialog.

MSBuild will compile the project but does nothing beyond that - my (lack of) web server logs indicate that MSBuild never even communicated with it.

```
msbuild.exe SiteAdmin/SiteAdmin.csproj
  /P:Configuration=Release
  /P:DeployOnBuild=True
  /P:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
  /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/MsDeploy.axd
  /P:DeployIisAppPath=BackOffice
  /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
  /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
  /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
  /P:UserName=username
  /P:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True
  /P:Password=password
```

The main difference between two two projects is the the working project uses web forms while the problematic project is MVC, though I can't imagine that accounting for anything. Am I missing some sort of setting that needs to be in the project files itself? Is there something else I'm glossing over here?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this

Comment: I never figured out the full solution. I ended up rebuilding the project/solution from scratch, and copying over the source code files.